# window.scrollTo(...) error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: javascript, vb.net, scroll, object-expected

I know there are a lot of post about this, but i've been looking to do this all day.
What i try to acheive here is to click on a row in a GridView, then bring the page to scroll to that position, like an anchor in html would do.

This, is my link that i'll use to scroll. I call a function in my js file. This is in my GridView.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="window.scrollTo(0, GetPosition(this))" CommandName="select" ID="InkSelect" Text="SELECT" />
```

Then, i call this function in my js file, linked like this, just in case:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~js/monjs.js"></script>
```

In monjs.js, here is the function:

```
function GetPosition(element) {
var top = 0;
var e = document.getElementById(element);
while (e.offsetParent != undefined && e.offsetParent != null) {
    top += e.offsetTop + (e.clientTop != null ? e.clientTop : 0);
    e = e.offsetParent;
}
return top;}
```

And Visual studio is highlighting this line:

```
...... <a onclick="window.scrollTo(0, GetPosition(this));" .....
```

I tried many other way to do this, registering a script in the vb file, hardcoding window.scrollTo(0,100) in the onclick attribute, i'm out of ideas. 
I tried row.focus, don't mention this one.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: NITPICK: `e` is a variable that is normally used for exceptions or event objects. Most developers will use elem, element, or anchor for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I managed to do something. AFter many many tries...
i used this in my aspx file:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return Move(this);" CommandName="select" ID="_row" Text="SELECT" />
```

In my aspx.vb file, i used this in my page load function:

```
Dim myScriptName As String = "MovePageScript"
    If (Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Page.GetType(), myScriptName)) Then
        Dim myScript As New StringBuilder()
        myScript.Append("<script type=""text/javascript""> function Move(element) {")
        myScript.Append("var top = 0;")
        myScript.Append("var e = typeof element === 'string' ? document.getElementById(element) : element;")
        myScript.Append("while (e.offsetParent != undefined && e.offsetParent != null) {")
        myScript.Append("top += e.offsetTop + (e.clientTop != null ? e.clientTop : 0);")
        myScript.Append("e = e.offsetParent; }")
        myScript.Append("window.scrollTo(0, top);")
        myScript.Append("return false;")
        myScript.Append("} </script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), myScriptName, myScript.ToString(), False)
    End If
```

And used this in my web.config file:

```
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true">
```

It cancels the selection of the row but at least it works... I'll have to check now if I can get this to work with Telerik's Ragrid XD

Answer (score 3):

```
 <a onclick="window.scrollTo(0, GetPosition(this));" 
                                              ^
                                              |
                                            An Object    
function GetPosition(element) {
    var top = 0;
    var e = document.getElementById(element);
                                      ^
                                      |
                                Expecting a string
```

You are passing in an object and acting like it is a string.

```
var e = document.getElementById(element);
```

needs to be

```
var e = element;
```

If your function needs to handle both an object or a string, you can either pass in `this.id` with the onclick handler

```
OnClientClick="window.scrollTo(0, GetPosition(this.id))"
```

or do a typeof check.

```
 var e = typpeof element === "string" ? document.getElementById(element) : element;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't get this to work tho. I'm getting the same error, on the same line. I tried the typeof, and sending this.id but none worked. I was wondering, in my aspx file, i placed my window.scrollTo into a OnClientClick, on runtime, the error is given in a onclick. Just wasking if this might be related or is it because of the select command.

Comment: And i tried to use `OnClientClick="window.scrollTo(0, 200)"` and it works perfectly fine... and i tried to remove the parameter `OnClientClick="window.scrollTo(0, GetPosition())"` and this triggers the error too. I am following this article to get this to work [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-ASPNet-GridView-SelectedRow-when-clicked-using-JavaScript.aspx)